# Empty files after AES, DES Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, text-files, aes

I have encrypted a .txt file using AES, tha file contains integers, and now I am trying to DECRYPT it as the code below:

```
   try {
   FileOutputStream outStream;
   CipherOutputStream cos;
   try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(pOld.toString())) {
       outStream = new FileOutputStream(pNew.toString());
       byte k[]= Key.getBytes();
       SecretKeySpec KEYY=new SecretKeySpec(k, EncAlgo);
       Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance(EncAlgo);
       enc.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, KEYY);
       cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream,enc);
       byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int read;
       while((read=file.read(buffer))!=-1)
       {

          cos.write(buffer, 0, read);
       }
   }
        outStream.flush();
        cos.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Message Was Decrypted Successfully");           
    }
 catch(HeadlessException | IOException | InvalidKeyException |      NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Decryption Failed");
 }
```

But the .txt result file decrypted is always empty!!!
Any ideas why that happens?
It shows me that the Decryption was successful, but the file.txt is empty!

Hence:
POld, PNew => Paths.txt
    /////    AncAlgo = "AES"
I have tried decrypting a .txt and a .jpg files, both were empty,,
and here is the Encryption code for specific AES, both have the same key off course::

```
 public static void EncryptFile(Path POld, String key, Path PNew)
{
    try {

        File FileOld = new File(POld.toString());
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(FileOld);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(FileOld);
        byte k[]= key.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec KEYY=new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KEYY);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream,enc);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read=file.read(buffer))!=-1){
            cos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        file.close();
        outStream.flush();
        cos.close();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Encrypted!");


    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found!");
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO Exception!");
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such padding!");
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Such Algorithm!");
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Key!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks OK at a glance. Did it complete successfully? No exceptions? How did you encrypt it? NB You don't need the flush().

Comment: Yes, It shows the message dialog that the decryption was successful..

It appears also that the picture it decrypts results into an empty .jpg file :$

Comment: Make up your mind. Is it a .txt file or a .jpg? Not that it matters. And where is the encrypting code I asked for?

Comment: I have edited the question, the encryption code is above, thx for pointing that,,
, and yes I have tried both .jpg and .txt.. both went empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the input file with a new output file in the encryption code. You're producing a zero length file. You need to produce a new file.

Comment: OH MY GOD,, Thanks ALOT :) (Y)
You're awesome :)